# Stubing Requests in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to stub HTTP requests using the webrequest API for chrome extensions.

The main aim of doing so is to be able to mock http responses in chrome. Is it at all possible?

I went through the documentation - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest
But couldn't find an api which would help me achieve this ?